# Take contents of UITextField and insert it into an online form, press button, and get result back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, forms, web-services, cocoa-touch

I hope that this flow chart adequately describes what I would like to happen.

[image: Flowchart describing what I want to happen]

The webpage in question is [here](http://archives.nd.edu/words.html). It is the top textbox and the "Latin to English" button. You can type in "Semper" as an example of how it outputs/works.

My Question: How in the world do you code this kind of thing?!

Thanks for helping on what seems to me like a huge request!

Comment: Have you considered asking the owners of that site if they could set up an API instead of you scraping their page? I'm not sure how legal scraping their page actually is.

Comment: @Kevin: The program is freeware, but old and is written in Ada. The site is probably not maintained, given _archives_.nd.edu and the formatting of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this url: http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?english= and attach the world.
So, If you called the text field textInput the code is this:

```
NSString *toTranslate = self.textInput.text;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?english=%@", toTranslate];
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:UTF8Encoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"Response %@", response);
```

If you want to have a single word you need to parse the response of the server, but it's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Just testing the URL, and if you want English to Latin, use English=, if you want Latin to English, use keyword=

Comment: Thanks! I used this in conjunction with a parsing library.